# How to send a flag when making request in angularJS $resource and check this flag in global interceptor

Tags: angularjs, resources, interceptor

Guys I am trying to set a flag when sending a request in $resource. Meantime I created a global interceptor. How can I check this flag in response and response error of the interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without seeing any code, but, you can set your flag in rootScope and in your injector you can inject rootScope and check your flag.